# Javascript ES6 retrieve members of class

Tags: javascript, class, reflection, ecmascript-6

The idea is to get the list of methods/properties of class. For example, I have this class:

```
// foo.js
class FooController {
    constructor() {
    }
    *bar(next) {
        yield next;
        return 'meh';
    }
    //,
    meh() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
module.exports = FooController;
```

Now I want to retrieve the member of `FooController`. This should be done easily for javascript **plain object**, but not with **class**:

```
// index.js
var Foo = require('foo');
var foo = new Foo();

// inspect
console.log(foo); // expected: { bar, meh }, but got {}

// struggle with lodash
var _ = require('lodash');    
console.log(_.keys(foo)); // expected ['bar', 'meh'], but got []
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Is that comma behind *bar intentional? I get a syntax error there.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was typo -- let me edit it and thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query the `prototype` object of the `Foo()` class instance:

```
// index.js
var Foo = require('foo');
var foo = new Foo();

var _ = require('lodash');    
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames((Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)))); // shows ['bar', 'meh', 'constructor']
// or
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo.__proto__)); // shows ['bar', 'meh', 'constructor']
```

The proposed `_.keys(foo)` returns only the owned properties of the object (`bar()` and `meh()` are inherited), which actually is empty`[]`.

To retrieve the methods you need:

- To access the `prototype` object of the instance
- Enumerate the properties of the `prototype`. Because the needed properties are not enumerable (`Object.keys()` or `_.keys()` won't work), it's necessary to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`.

See more about [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbLqg7h9/1/) for a complete example.

Comment: at my end, it shows `[]` instead of `['bar', 'meh']`

Comment: @Adiono Oops. Answer updated.

Comment: Cool! it's working now, thanks Dmitri!

Answer (score 2):

`class`es in ES6 are just sugar coding over defining methods on a function's `prototype` in ES5. So for your example:

```
class FooController {
    constructor() {
    }
    *bar(next) {
        yield next;
        return 'meh';
    }
    //,
    meh() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
module.exports = FooController;
```

the ES5 equivalent is:

```
var FooController = (function() {
    function FooController() { } // This method will act as our constructor

    // All methods defined on the prototype are equivalent with the
    // so called class methods in ES6
    FooController.prototype.bar = *function(next) { yield next; return 'meh'; };

    FooController.prototype.meh = function() { return 'bar'; };

    return FooController;
})();
```

to access the "public" methods of off `FooController` you can either:

1. Access the prototype explicitly like so: `FooController.prototype`

   `console.log(FooController.prototype.meh()) // => 'bar'`
2. Access the prototype of the constructed object likes so:

   `var foo = new FooController();
   var proto = foo.__proto__; 
   console.log(proto.meh()) // => 'bar'`

When you construct `foo` calling the `new` keyword, amoung other, these few steps will occour:

1. A new object will be created
2. The prototype of that object will point to the prototype of `FooController`;

As long as you think of `class methods` as sugar coding over `prototype` methods it becomes much easier to gain power over the situation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not working, it shows `[]` on both ways (see: https://jsfiddle.net/budiadiono/r2wdgkmk/1/). I think I'm going to use @Dmitri Pavlutin's answer.

Comment: `meh` and `bar` are not enumerable properties. That's why `Object.keys()` is not working.

Comment: Yes, Dimitri is right. I will edit my answer. You can access the methods directly from the prototype, you cannot list them using the `keys()` method.

Comment: Ah I see it now, good explanation! thanks Andrei!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: you can print the `class constructor`, wich gives the desired result:

```
class FooController {
    constructor() {
    }
    *bar(next) {
        yield next;
        return 'meh';
    }
    meh() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}


var foo = new FooController();

console.log(foo.constructor);

function class FooController {
    constructor() {
    }
    *bar(next) {
        yield next;
        return 'meh';
    }
    meh() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

Option 2: you can just print the `class object` without binding it:

```
class FooController {
    constructor() {
    }
    *bar(next) {
        yield next;
        return 'meh';
    }
    meh() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

console.log(FooController);

function class FooController {
    constructor() {
    }
    *bar(next) {
        yield next;
        return 'meh';
    }
    meh() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how to retrieve the members, not how to print the blueprint.

Comment: Yes, @zeroflagL is right! I want members not the blueprint.